# Program to edit Default Applications (for MIME types)

Tags: files, arch-linux, desktop

Is there some nice programm (not necessary with GUI but would be nice) to edit my preferred applications for MIME types?

I want to change e. g. default browser and default image viewer without relying on the program to ask me to do it.

(I'm using Arch Linux + i3wm)

Comment: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/perl-file-mimeinfo/

Answer (score 0):

A few programs from the official repositories that could help:

> extra/perl-file-mimeinfo : Determine file type, includes mimeopen and
>   mimetype
>   extra/perl-mime-tools : Parses streams to create MIME entities

The first one, as pointed out in a comment, is probably particularly helpful:

```
pacman -Syu [--asdeps] perl-file-mimeinfo perl-mime-tools
```

Comment: perl-anyevent-i3 does not deal with mime types in any way.

Comment: Yes, I lost track of your actual question there.  My apologies and I removed that from my answer.